# Can a managed thread call a C++ method that calls boost asio async_write

Tags: visual-c++, pinvoke, boost-asio, multithreading

I am writing a client in C# that is communicating with a Windows C++ DLL that uses boost asio asynchronous calls.  I have read before that ASIO does not work too well in a managed environment.  The VC++ DLL is an unmanaged project that creates an unmanaged thread for the I/O handlers.  The C# code creates a background thread to handle sending messages to the C++ DLL via pinvoke.  My question is - can the call to the boost::asio::async_write method be on a managed thread?  Or, does it have to be on an unmanaged thread?

It will help simplify the logic and processing if I can make the call to async_write on the managed thread.  But, I'm worried about what might happen when the .NET garbage collector runs and stops the threads.  I don't know if ASIO will be able to handle that or not.  I'm not passing any pointers to data defined in the C# code, so that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notion of a "managed thread" is a weak one, the operating system only supports one kind of thread.  A thread that runs managed code isn't special, managed code gets translated to the exact same kind of machine code that a C compiler generates.  The only difference is that the CLR knows about the thread and will have a reason to have a look at its stack when a garbage collection occurs.  Necessary to find stack frames of managed code that may contain object references.

It will *not* be interested in any stack frames that belong to native code, it simply ignores them.  And yes, the thread may be paused while the GC performs the search but only if it is currently executing managed code.  Native code keeps running, it will only block when it returns back to a managed method if a GC is in progress.  This pause isn't otherwise different from any other kind of reason a thread may pause, including losing the processor for a while when the operating system scheduler runs something else.

So using boost::asio is fine, nothing goes wrong.  Just as the many other ways that a managed program can execute native code, including operating system calls.  The only detail you'll want to take care of is making sure that your code gets compiled without /clr in effect.  Compiling boost code to IL works fine, it just isn't very efficient.